# Put some environment on left column and some others on right in article with twocolumn option

Tags: environments, page-breaking, two-column

I use the `article class` with the `twocolumn` option.
I would like to put definition environments on the left column and example environments on the right column.

For example :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
    Definition 1
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    Example 1
\end{example}

\begin{definition}
    Definition 2
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    Example 2
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

should put the definitions 1 and 2 on the left column and the examples 1 and 2 on the right column.
(of course, I need the following of the left column of the first page to continue on the left column of the second page, and the same for the right columns)

The definition X and example X don't have to be on the same line.
To be more specific I would like it to be "as if" there were two tex files compiled : the first one wich contains only the definitions and wich is displayed on the left side of each page, and the second one wich contains only the examples and wich is displayed on the right side of each page.

Comment: The environment content must be aligned too, i.e. definition X and example X starting on the same line?

Comment: for latex this is a one column document not two, you want the definitions to be in the main body and example to be some variant of `\marginpar`

Answer (score 4):

Not precisely what the O.P. wants to have (not `twocolumn` mode and **automatically**), but parallel with `parallel` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}{0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
  \ParallelLText{%
  \begin{definition}
    Cauchy Sequence
  \end{definition}
}
\ParallelRText{%
 \begin{example}
    $a_{n} = \dfrac{1}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence
  \end{example}
}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{%
  \begin{definition}
    Cauchy Sequence
  \end{definition}
}
\ParallelRText{%
 \begin{example}
    $a_{n} = \dfrac{1}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence
  \end{example}
}
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar result can be obtained with the `paracol` package.

Comment: Perhaps I can use some setup of my `jumplines` package to get a better result. But not tonight ... it's late here!

Comment: Your suggestion is cool, but my document uses the class `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` (I've modified the post to be more specific).
So your solution does not fit.

Comment: @math45 As David mentioned in the comments, the layout you want needs to be a single column document. You can't do this with `twocolumn`.

Comment: @math45 you can't do what you ask for with `twocolumn` option. What  Christian propose is the answer even if i prefer `paracol` which make switch automatically.

Comment: @touhami: Yes, I will probably use another version with `paracol` then.